# Including variables in the json put request using python

Tags: python, json, python-requests, postman, put

I have a basic python sensor and it reads temperature and pressure and saved them to a variable.

I would like to use this variable as a parameter in the python request body in JSON format. Is that possible?

I get an error saying bad request and another one convert to double from str error:

```
import requests

url = "https://10.109.143.88:8443/sendsensorvalue/"

payload = "{\n\t\t\"pantherId\":2741025,\n\t\t\"values\":[\n\t\t{\n\t\t\t\"variableName\":\"Temperature\",\n\t\t\t\"timeStamp\":1507268051,\n\t\t\t\"value\":33\n\t\t},\n\t\t{\n\t\t\t\"variableName\":\"Pressure\",\n\t\t\t\"timeStamp\":1507268051,\n\t\t\t\"value\":33\n\t\t}\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t]\n}"
headers = {
    'content-type': "application/json",
    'cache-control': "no-cache",
    'postman-token': "6dde2794-7133-5666-560a-c09e4761ed35"
    }

response = requests.request("PUT", url, data=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

This runs fine with predefined values of 33 for temperature and pressure data.

I have this same code running to get sensor data and store it in variables

```
import requests
import Adafruit_BMP.BMP085 as BMP085
sensor=BMP085.BMP085()

rawTemp=sensor.read_temperature()
rawPressure=sensor.read_pressure()
```

I want to be able to assign value in rawTemp to the JSON value (the 33 value) and send it to the server.

Comment: Please post your code and the traceback or other error messages.

Comment: edited post to show original code

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer.

you can have payload split into multiple strings and add them while having the input from variables be converted to string.

```
payload = "{\n\t\t\"pantherId\":2741025,\n\t\t\"values\":[\n\t\t{\n\t\t\t\"variableName\":\"Temperature\",\n\t\t\t\"timeStamp\":1507268051,\n\t\t\t\"value\":"+str(variableName1)+"\n\t\t},\n\t\t{\n\t\t\t\"variableName\":\"Pressure\",\n\t\t\t\"timeStamp\":1507268051,\n\t\t\t\"value\":"+str(variableName2)+"\n\t\t}\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t]\n}"
```